# Access image from cache loaded in MvxImageLoadingView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have an image that is loaded via URL into a `MvxImageLoadingView`. How can I access this image from the image cache?

I have tried using the `FFImageLoading.ImageService` but I cant access it there.

Where do I access this cache?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, doesn't it give you the image if you provide the URL again?

Comment: What I ended up having to do was create a new instance of `MvxImageLoadingView`, pass it the URL and then access the `Image` property of that view. I want the `UIImage` so that I can pass it to the `UIActivityController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was this. I created a new instance of `MvxImageLoadingView`, gave it the URL, and then accessed the `Image` property to get the `UImage` for the URL.

Not the optimal solution but the only one that I could find thus far.